# Let  ⊆  be the subset given by  ≔ { ∈  ∶ ^ = ||^ }

Tags: general-topology

For every integer $n \in\mathbb N^*$ , let $X_n \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be the subset given by $X_n ≔ \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^n = ||^ \}$.
If $m \neq n$, then $X_m$ is not homeomorphic to $X_n$.

I am asked to prove or disprove this. Could anyone please give me a hint

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question in wrongly. I have corrected it now

Comment: Hint: $z \in X_n$ implies $z^n$ is real.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** $X_n$ is a collection of $n$ rays connected in the origin.
Note that $0$ is the only point of $X_n$ which doesn't have a neighborhood of the shape of an open interval (unless $n=2$), and there are $n$ segments starting out from it in any neighborhood of it.